# Options for traveling to Corsica from NYC

Tags: france, us-citizens, corsica

I live in NYC and am looking to travel to Corsica for a few weeks next summer to visit my boyfriend, who's from Bastia. From what I can ascertain the options are taking a flight from either Paris or Marseille; it would be nice to stop in Marseille for a day, but this isn't necessary.
I had a few questions pertaining to this:

- Are there any direct connections from NYC to Marseille? I wasn't able to find any, but was perhaps overlooking something.
- Are there any connections from CDG airport to Bastia, or are all of them from Orly?
- What's the usual way to transfer from CDG to Orly these days? I've heard that some services (e.g. the shuttle bus) are cancelled / interrupted due to the pandemic.

Any other comments would be welcome, as it's my first time flying alone. I don't anticipate any issues entering France as I'm vaccinated, but am aware that it is a rapidly changing situation.

Comment: CDG > ORY is a long transfer. Did you search for flights from one of the NY airports directly to Orly?

Comment: Air France is currently running a CDG–BIA flight a few days each week, but that service appears to end in January.

Comment: Also, Delta and United will (according to FlightConnections.com) be resuming non-stop service between New York and Nice in the spring.   Nice might be a reasonable substitute for Marseille.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert fly to Nice and ferry is how I'd do it transatlantic (train to Nice starting from the UK, if only we could...).  Nice is nice and has a well-served airport, though Marseille is supposed to be an interesting city

Comment: There used to be a direct connection between NYC and Corsica, it was called the French Connection. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Air France seems the way to go. They do have a daily flight from JFK to Orly and occasional (not every day of the week) flights from CDG to Bastia as well.

Availability depends on your specific dates. I checked for June.